# discord.js how do I record a username for future use without mentioning the recorded user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to build a bot that has a points system and leaderboard of the users with the most points. Unfortunately, I cannot mention the top 5 players on the leaderboard everytime someone calls the command. I've tried msg.author.id and msg.author.username and can't seem to record the needed information. .id only records a series of numbers that can be used to mention the user later with <@${msg.author.id}> but .username is constantly undefined. I wonder if I'm using the .username function incorrectly or if there is another method that can do this. I also tried using the mention function within code text via ```` and while it removed the mention it did not show the name of the user, just the numbers.

````
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId ="${msg.author.id}"`).then(row => { // Level System
    if (!row) {
        sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, daily, points, level, glimmer, wr, rotw, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [msg.author.id, 0, 0, 0, 500, 0, 0, msg.author.username]);
        //msg.channel.send(`Welcome <@${msg.author.id}>! Thank you for joining Playing Destiny Fast! You start off with 500 glimmer!`);
        console.log("new player added to database");
    } else {
        sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points + 1} WHERE userId = ${msg.author.id}`);
        let curLevel = Math.floor(0.02 * row.points + 1);
        if (row.level > 100 || curLevel > 100) { row.level = 100; msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> has already achieved the highest level! Thank you for your continued support!`) }
        if (curLevel > row.level) {
            row.level = curLevel;
            sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points + 1}, level = ${row.level} WHERE userId = ${msg.author.id}`);
            msg.reply(`has reached level ${curLevel}!`);
        }
    }
}).catch(() => {
    console.error;
    console.log("Table doesn't exist. Compiling...");
    sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, daily INTEGER, points INTEGER, level INTEGER, glimmer INTEGER, wr INTEGER, rotw INTEGER, name TEXT)").then(() => {
        sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, daily, points, level, glimmer, wr, rotw, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [msg.author.id, 0, 0, 0, 500, 0, 0, msg.author.username]);
        msg.channel.send(`<@Programmer> I've encountered a critical error in the database. Please ensure that there is nothing wrong with my primary objective.`);
    });
});
if (cat === "level") {
    sql.all(`SELECT userId, level FROM scores ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT ${amount}`).then(rows => {
        tops.length = 0;
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            tops.push(`\n ${row.name} -- ${row.level}`);
        });
    embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`Failsafe`)
        .setColor(0x7EC0EE)
        .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/1XPQkeC.jpg")
        .setDescription("---------------------------------------------------------------")
        .setFooter("")
        .addField(StringFormat(`Top ${amount} Users: ${cat}`, [NumShown]), "```" + tops.join('') + "```");
            msg.channel.send(embed);
    });
}
````

I'm using Microsoft visual studios 2017, Node.js 8x, with discord.js, cheerio, sqlite, node-pre-gyp, and sqlite 3 as the primary libraries. I'm on windows 10 using a single sqlite file to store the collected data into a single table with only rows and columns. I am NOT getting any error messages just an incorrect output. It currently outputs the user's number or "undefined" for use in the mention drop down syntax but I want to display the name of the user without mentioning them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the name column I was selecting the userId column. This meant that the name column was never checked and made the result undefined. .id is great for storing specific users while .username is best for determining a player's name. Everything is used correctly but I had to make the following modification.

```
sql.all(`SELECT name, level FROM scores ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT ${amount}`).then(rows => {
```